# How to call sql stored procedures that needs to specify parameters in Matlab

Tags: sql, matlab

Hello my first posting here: 
I am trying to call a sql stored procedure in Matlab, and the sql stored procedure requires me to specify start_date and end_date. I am new to Matlab, below is what I have created within the function to call sql stored procedure in Matlab:

```
SQL_TO_MATLAB= DataImport()
conn=database('ABC')
inputargs = {'start_date','end_date'}
SqlCurs=exec(conn,'sp_Get_Asset_Class_Returns',inputargs)
Matlabdata = fetch(SqlCurs)
```

My question is: if I would like to specify start_date as 2012/04/30, end_date as 2016/04/30, where I should indicate these two dates within this function?

Thanks a lot for your kind advise!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the correct function to use is `runstoredprocedure`.

I'm not setup to test this right now, but I suspect the calling convention would look something like this (assuming the result of the stored procedure was a resultSet):

```
SQL_TO_MATLAB= DataImport()
conn=database('ABC')
x = runstoredprocedure(conn, 'sp_Get_Asset_Class_Returns',{'2012/04/30' '2016/04/30'})
Matlabdata = fetch(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Highly appreciate it. I tried your way and it still did not return any data. Do you know what could possible cause the error? Also, if I don't define inputargs as "start_date, end_date, and just put in dates like your script, my Matlab function would not be flexible enough to change the date. Right?

Comment: If it works, you could use variables to generate a flexible Matlab script. It's hard to debug from here ... the next thing I would try is different date formats. You may need to find someone who knows the stored procedure well, in any language.